# Passing unknown/mixed types to printf() using void* pointer (kind of infering the type at runtime)

Tags: c, pointers, casting, printf

I'm trying to pass mixed types to `printf()`. In the actual code (at the bottom) I also pass the format placeholder so that `printf()` knows how to format.

While accidently using these `void*` pointers directly as call by values, I discovered that my code was not working as expected.

So I created a test program, searched and poked around until I came up with this solution.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test1(void* a) {
    printf("value: %d\n", *(int*)a);
}

void test2(void* a) {
    printf("value: %f\n", *(float*)a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int* aip = &(int){1};
    test1(aip);

    int ai = 1;
    test1(&ai);

    float af = 1.75;
    test2(&af);

    return 0;
}
```

But I don't want hardcoded `*(int*)` or `*(float*)` dereferencing and casting but actually write something like this:

```
void test(void* a) {
    printf("value: %VARIES\n", a);
}
```

`VARIES` is passed into `test()` and concatenated into the final formatter string.

The actual function looks like this:

```
void fn(void* value, char* fmtChar) {
    char fmtHelper[50];
    // fill fmtChar in formatter string's %s placeholder
    snprintf(fmtHelper, sizeof(fmtHelper), "value : %s\n", fmtChar);
    // actually print value varying argument
    printf(fmtHelper, value);   
}
```

My curent workaround uses `switch`/`case` statements and determines the casting and formatter placeholders programmatically.

Comment: OK, so what is the question?

Comment: The `%d` format code (for example) requires an `int` argument, not an `int*`. It's easy to insert a format code into a format string, but how do you propose to turn a `void*` into an `int` without knowing what the `void*` really points at?

Comment: Um, how do you turn a 32/64-bit (void *) into a 32-bit int?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: "`... but actually write something like this`". @rici, I know that `int*` would print the address. I thought my `*(int*)` makes a cast to `int`-pointer which is then dereferenced. If I'm wrong with that, please tell me. But since I told the compiler the type it knows how to deal with the data. However, my goal is to pass uncertain types. To your question: maybe there's a `printf()` alternative that justs reads `N` bytes at the pointer depending on the formatting code. But I guess my misunderstanding is that `printf()` does not determine the value by the formatting code...

Comment: The _format_ to `printf()` directs how the function should interpret the following arguments.  The _format_ does not affect the arguments in any way.  If the format is consistent with the type of arguments, all is well.,  if not, then UB happens.

Comment: `*(int*)` does what you say, and by analogy, so does `*(double*)`. But you want to be able to do `fn("%6.3f", (void*)d)`. Now, the implementation of `fn` needs to know that it has to use `*(double*)` in the argument list for `printf`, and not `*(int*)`. There is *nothing* you can write which will automatically choose the right one, since a `void*` has no clue as to what it originally pointed at. So you're going to need to analyse the format code with a switch statement, which you say you don't want to do.

Comment: `printf` uses the format code to figure out how to interpret the value, yes. But it does not dereference a pointer; you have to do that before passing the value to `printf`. And so the dereferenced value better have the type you told `printf` it was, because `printf` will unquestioningly believe what you said. Lying to printf is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Anyway, this all has the feel of an X-Y problem. Maybe you should step back a bit, and ask a question about what you really want to do. You can forward entire varargs argument lists to another function, for example; `vprintf` exists precisely to facilitate that idiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're targeting current C (C11), you can use a type-generic expression with a macro to make a type-generic function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_int(int x) {
    printf("an int: %d\n", x);
}

void print_double(double x) {
    printf("a double: %f\n", x);
}

#define print(X) _Generic((X),             \
                     float: print_double,  \
                     double: print_double, \
                     default: print_int    \
                 )(X)

int main(void) {
    print(1);   // an int: 1
    print(1.0); // a double: 1.00000
}
```

Comment: [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) may interest you?

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `vprintf` and `va_list` macros, so they're resolved during the preprocessing of the source.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void print(char* msg, char* fmtChars, ...) {
    // format string and write the result to fmtHelper
    // %s is replaced with the value placeholder types
    // (fixed length for simplicity)
    char fmtHelper[50];
    snprintf(fmtHelper, sizeof(fmtHelper), "%s; value 1: %s, value 2: %s\n", msg, fmtChars, fmtChars);

    va_list args;
    // treat all parameters _after_ this named as variable arg
    va_start(args, fmtChars);
    vprintf(fmtHelper, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void) {
    char* msg = "Test";
    int in1 = 1;
    int in2 = 2;
    float fl1 = 4.21;
    float fl2 = 5.89;
    print(msg, "%f", fl1, fl2);
    print(msg, "%d", in1, in2);
}
```

This was a hint @rici gave in the comments section.